# How to determine .net platform at runtime from portable library?

Tags: c#, silverlight, runtime, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

Specifically I want to be able to determine at runtime when portable class library code is running on Silverlight, WinRT, or .NET

My best idea right now is:

```
typeof(object).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyProductAttribute>().Product
```

On .NET it returns "Microsoft® .NET Framework" and on Silverlight it returns "Microsoft® Silverlight"  but I'm not sure if it distinguishes itself on WinRT as I'm not developing with Windows 8 at the moment.

So I'd like to know if that works or any better ideas.

Comment: Interesting question. I created a portable library which I referenced from one Windows Store app, and from one WP8 app. Discouragingly enough, the WS app returns "Microsoft® .NET Framework" and the WP8 app returns "Microsoft® Silverlight". By the way, your line as it stands right now does not work in a portable library. Try `((AssemblyProductAttribute)typeof(object).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute), false)[0]).Product` instead.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thanks,for testing it. Maybe I'll need to investigate polling for types only available on certain platforms with `Type.GetType(string)`

Comment: @AndersGustafsson thinking about it more, the WP8 thing really isn't an issue since I presume Environment.OSVersion is correct on WP8. Distinguishing WinRT from .NET 4.5 on a Windows 8 intel machine seems to be the challenge.

Comment: Can you provide more information on why you want to do this? We recommend feature detection (ie does this type/method exist) over platform detection because platforms change over time.

Comment: @DavidKean So I guess the issues becomes that there are large swaths of api that are close but don't overlap, so if you make your library PCL and you extract those bits that were full of #if into platform specific support dlls. If I do feature detection then I need to call each specific feature with reflection which would be a lot and really confusing. What I'd rather do is platform detection and load a platform named dll with Assembly.Load(string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are usually very few good reasons for it, here's a class that does so:

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/onovotny/MvvmLightPortable/changeset/view/f356af74426f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Portable/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Helpers/DesignerPlatformLibrary.cs

I use it as part of logic to determine IsInDesignTime for a PCL.